# How to add Rtools\bin to the system path in R

Tags: r, shiny

Am running a Shiny app from https://github.com/MikeJSeo/SAM
and the code to access it:

```
install.packages(c("samr", "matrixStats", "GSA", "shiny", "openxlsx"))
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("impute")
library(shiny)
runGitHub("SAM", "MikeJSeo")
```

The app runs great but I get a error when trying to save the output. This is the error I obtain:

```
Warning: Error in : zipping up workbook failed. Please make sure Rtools is installed or a zip application is available to R.
Try installr::install.rtools() on Windows. If the "Rtools\bin" directory does not appear in Sys.getenv("PATH") please add it to the system PATH 
or set this within the R session with Sys.setenv("R_ZIPCMD" = "path/to/zip.exe")
```

I tried;

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

and the output is

```
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.1\\bin\\x64;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\ActivIdentity\\ActivClient\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ActivIdentity\\ActivClient\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Addinsoft\\XLSTAT\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\"
```

Am assuming that my error arrises because I dont have the "Rtools\bin" directory. I have tried,

```
Sys.setenv("R_ZIPCMD" = "mypath/to/zip.exe")
```

but not luck. So how can I go about correcting this?

Answer (score 21):

This fixed my problem.

```
library(devtools)
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/Rtools/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/")
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. But I keep needing to set `Rtools` to the system path everytime I open RStudio in my nem PC. Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 10):

To answer to John Doe's question, you can make sure that Rtools is in the path always and only for R by adding this line to your `.Rprofile`:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/Rtools/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
```

`.Rprofile` needs to be located at the path pointed by the command `Sys.getenv("HOME")`.