# How is to add R and Rtools paths in the environment variable?

Tags: r, path, environment-variables, r-package

I have installed `R-3.5.1` and `Rtools35.exe`. But I am unable to install packages in `R`. Somewhere I got,

> Make sure the R and Rtools paths are added in the environment variable.

But I don't know what is environment variable and how is to add  R and Rtools paths in the environment variable?

#### Edit

The answer provided [How to add Rtools\bin to the system path in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539125/how-to-add-rtools-bin-to-the-system-path-in-r) requires `library(devtools)`. But `install.packages("devtools")` isn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Rtools\bin to the system path in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539125/how-to-add-rtools-bin-to-the-system-path-in-r)

Comment: @Hunaidkhan The answer provided there, requires `library(devtools)`. But `install.packages("devtools")` doesn't work too.

Comment: Set the `BINPREF` environment variable. See eg [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Setting-the-path-to-Rtools-for-package-compilation-on-Windows-td4748266.html).

Comment: devtools should work once rtools is added to the environment please add rtools to environment restart the R session and try again

Comment: @Hunaidkhan My question is how is to add rtools to the environment?

Comment: In the start menu type Environment variable -> open Environment variable -> System Variables -> Path -> enter R tools and R bin path here.

Answer (score 1):

Installing package that has heavy dependencies just to set environment variables doesn't seem to be good solution.

Below solution is for R 4.0.0 and rtools40.

This uses powershell bash, it should be available on all recent Windows versions.

```sh
$ENV:PATH = "C:\R\bin;C:\rtools40\usr\bin;$ENV:PATH"
```

You can see full R 4.0.0 setup on Windows in [this CI yaml](https://gitlab.com/jangorecki/r.gitlab.ci/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml).

---

Note that in powershell it is best to refer to applications using `.exe` suffix, because powershell has many aliases, so using `R` or `curl` will not do what you expect, you need `R.exe` or `curl.exe` instead.