# Cannot install an R package from Github

Tags: r

I'm trying to run `devtools::install_github("gaborcsardi/notifier")` but R does not appear to be properly recognizing RTools; which is located in `C:\Rtools`.

After following the instructions on https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1772, running `pkgbuild::find_rtools()` still gives me the following error using the CRAN version of `devtools` and `pkgbuild`:

`Error in rethrow_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), stdin,  : 
  Command not found @win/processx.c:977`

Here is my `session_info()`:

```
- Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Chicago             
 date     2019-09-03                  

- Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ! package         * version   date       lib source        
   assertthat        0.2.1     2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   backports         1.1.4     2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   bindr             0.1.1     2018-03-13 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   bindrcpp          0.2.2     2018-03-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   bit               1.1-14    2018-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   bit64             0.9-7     2017-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   blob              1.1.1     2018-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   callr             3.3.1     2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   cellranger        1.1.0     2016-07-27 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   cli               1.1.0     2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   crayon            1.3.4     2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   curl              3.3       2019-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   data.table        1.12.2    2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   DBI               1.0.0     2018-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   desc              1.2.0     2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   devtools        * 2.1.0     2019-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   digest            0.6.19    2019-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   dplyr           * 0.7.8     2018-11-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   fs                1.3.1     2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 D glue              1.3.1     2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   hms               0.4.2     2018-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   httr            * 1.4.0     2018-12-11 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   jsonlite          1.6       2018-12-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   lubridate       * 1.7.4     2018-04-11 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   magrittr          1.5       2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   mailR           * 0.4.1     2015-01-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   memoise           1.1.0     2017-04-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   odbc            * 1.1.6     2018-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   packrat           0.5.0     2018-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   pillar            1.4.1     2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   pkgbuild        * 1.0.5     2019-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   pkgconfig         2.0.2     2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   pkgload           1.0.2     2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   plyr              1.8.4     2016-06-08 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   prettyunits       1.0.2     2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   processx        * 3.4.1     2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   ps                1.3.0     2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   purrr             0.3.2     2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   R.methodsS3       1.7.1     2016-02-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   R.oo              1.22.0    2018-04-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   R.utils           2.8.0     2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   R6                2.4.0     2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   Rcpp              1.0.1     2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   RDCOMClient     * 0.93-0    2018-04-28 [1] local         
   readxl          * 1.3.1     2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   rematch           1.0.1     2016-04-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   remotes           2.1.0     2019-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   reshape         * 0.8.8     2018-10-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 D rJava             0.9-11    2019-03-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   rlang             0.4.0     2019-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   rprojroot         1.3-2     2018-01-03 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   rstudioapi        0.10      2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   rvest           * 0.3.4     2019-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   sessioninfo       1.1.1     2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   splitstackshape * 1.4.8     2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   stringi           1.4.3     2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   stringr           1.4.0     2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 D testthat          2.1.1     2019-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   tibble            2.1.1     2019-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   tidyr           * 0.8.3     2019-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   tidyselect        0.2.5     2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   usethis         * 1.5.0     2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   withr             2.1.2     2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
   writexl         * 1.1       2018-12-02 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   XML             * 3.98-1.19 2019-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
   xml2            * 1.2.0     2018-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)

[1] \\termna.local/Shares/User Shares/Kyle.Dixon/Documents/R/win-library/3.5
[2] \\termna.local/Shares/User Shares/Kyle.Dixon/Documents/R/R-3.5.2/library

 D -- DLL MD5 mismatch, broken installation.
```

Comment: have you added rtools to your path as shown in this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47557831/7590064

Comment: Consider using `install_github` from `remotes` and not `devtools`. Perhaps there will not be a dependecy on Rtools. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/remotes/versions/2.1.0/topics/install_github

Comment: @Not_Dave Yes, running `Sys.getenv("PATH")` gives me: `C:/Rtools/bin;` as the first item.

Comment: @Omri374 I've tried using `remotes` as well but it runs into the same issue.

Comment: I've got the same problem on two different computers. Something is going wrong with when "pkgbuild::has_rtools` calls `callr::rcmd_safe`. Note, `remotes::install_github` is the same function as `devtools::install_github`.

Comment: Does it work if your package library (`.libPaths()`) is not a network share?

Comment: Just fyi, I'm getting exactly this same error in the same context as the OP as of two weeks ago. I have been unable to solve it. Following.

Comment: @r2evans Bingo. Thanks. Changed .libpaths to use a non-network drive, and also changed Rstudio to run R from a non-network drive and I can install from github.

Comment: @sissypants, did that also resolve your issue? Historically I have seen two types of issues on windows when running R: (1) spaces in the path (where R resides, not necessarily basic file access) has caused problems, I don't know if it still does since I now resort to always installing under `c:\R\R-3.5.3\...` and `c:\Rtools\...`; and (2) I don't know that I've ever had reliable windows UNC path use in R, I've had better luck with true letter-mounts (e.g., `G:\path` in lieu of `\\servername\sharename\path`). There might also be file-locking issues when using a share for packages, not certain.

Comment: KyleDixon and @RichardTelford, does this seem to address the underlying issue? If so, I can expand on my comment above as an answer, but only if it seems to address the OP sufficiently. (Kyle, if you no longer have the problem, perhaps you'd still be willing to weigh and and/or accept an answer if presented?)

Comment: I'm happy for you to expand your comment into an answer warning of the problems of UNC paths with R (they have confused me before with git)

Comment: @r2evans It makes sense to change `.libPaths()` to a non-network drive. I'll see if this works. It now dawns on me I have this problem only on my work PC where I a using a library collection on the network supported by core services (which is nice), but I may have to migrate to local installation of all libraries I need on my PC.  I do not have any of these issues on my home laptop where I use local library paths only. I also don't have this problem on my institution's HPC or AWS, obviously, which are not Windows OS.

Answer (score 4):

It's not uncommon for utilities (in R or other languages/tools) to be able to deal with simple file paths and schema-based URLs (e.g., `https://...` or `file:///...`), I think the number of tools that equally deal with Windows' UNC paths (i.e., `\\server\share\path`) is much less. While I believe that R is doing it just fine for finding the files (otherwise you'd have other problems by having your only two `.libPaths()` be UNC shares), the underlying tools (including `gcc`) might not.

I think the way-forward is to install the new package(s) into a directory that is not a network share. I also think this *can* be a temporary location, where the packages, once installed, can be moved/migrated over to the network share.

Below is a function that simplifies creation of a temporary directory, install to that directory, then move to the network share. (It doesn't actually check if the `tgt` directory is a network share, the assumption is that you would not need to use this is your first library path is local.)

```r
#' Install a package(s) using a temp-local directory
#'
#' On Windows, if '.libPaths()' starts with a UNC network share,
#' package compilation might not work correctly. This function creates
#' a temporary local directory, executes the desired code in 'expr',
#' and moves any new packages into the normal first library path.
#' 
#' @param expr expression such as 'install.packages("car")' or
#'   'devtools::install_github(...)'; the expression must natively
#'   install into the first of '.libPaths()', but if you try something
#'   like 'install.packages(.., lib="some/other/path"), then the
#'   temporary libpath will not be used (and may fail)
#' @param tgt character, the directory to move the isntalled
#'   package(s)
#' @param cleanup logical, whether to remove the temporary libpath
#' @return nothing
with_local_libpath <- function(expr, tgt = .libPaths()[1], cleanup = TRUE) {
  if (length(tgt) > 1) {
    warning("'tgt' must be length 1")
    tgt <- tgt[[1]]
  }
  if (length(tgt) < 1 || !dir.exists(tgt)) {
    stop("'tgt' must be length 1 and an existing directory")
  }

  dir.create(tmplib <- tempfile(pattern = "local_libpath_"))
  message("Local (temp) libpath: ", sQuote(tmplib))
  oldlib <- .libPaths()
  .libPaths(c(tmplib, oldlib))
  on.exit(.libPaths(oldlib), add = TRUE)

  force(expr)

  newstuff <- list.files(tmplib, full.names = TRUE)
  if (length(newstuff)) {
    newdirs <- file.path(oldlib[1], basename(newstuff))
    message("New packages found: ", paste(sQuote(basename(newstuff)), collapse = ", "))
    message("Moving to: ", sQuote(tgt))
    file.copy(newstuff, tgt, recursive = TRUE)
    if (cleanup) {
      message("Cleaning up")
      unlink(tmplib, recursive = TRUE)
    }
  } else {
    message("No new packages found (?)")
  }
  invisible()
}
```

I tested this with some simple examples, but not extensively, so caveat emptor. I don't have a network-mounted lib-path, so I'll force one (to a server I maintain):

```r
.libPaths(c("\\\\myserver/r2evans/R/win.library/3.5", .libPaths()))
```

Failing installation:

```r
remotes::install_github("gaborcsardi/notifier@d92b1b6")
# Downloading GitHub repo gaborcsardi/notifier@d92b1b6
# v  checking for file 'C:\Users\r2\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWgKbkW\remotes43cc57193c83\gaborcsardi-notifier-d92b1b6/DESCRIPTION' (377ms)
# -  preparing 'notifier':
# v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
# -  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
# -  checking for empty or unneeded directories
# -  building 'notifier_1.0.0.tar.gz'
#    
# Installing package into '\\myserver/r2evans/R/win.library/3.5'
# (as 'lib' is unspecified)
# * installing *source* package 'notifier' ...
# ** R
# ** inst
# Error in file.create(to[okay]) : 
#   (converted from warning) cannot create file '\myserver/r2evans/R/win.library/3.5/notifier/R.ico', reason 'No such file or directory'
# * removing '\\myserver/r2evans/R/win.library/3.5/notifier'
# In R CMD INSTALL
# Error: Failed to install 'notifier' from GitHub:
#   (converted from warning) installation of package 'C:/Users/r2/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWgKbkW/file43cc60c05cc/notifier_1.0.0.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
```

(I chose a specific version because of https://github.com/gaborcsardi/notifier/issues/22. While the error is different than your error, I suspect that the failure is for a similar/related reason.)

Successful installation:

```r
with_local_libpath(remotes::install_github("gaborcsardi/notifier@d92b1b6"))
# Local (temp) libpath: 'C:\Users\r2\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWgKbkW\local_libpath_43ccbf98e2'
# Downloading GitHub repo gaborcsardi/notifier@d92b1b6
# v  checking for file 'C:\Users\r2\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWgKbkW\remotes43cc7cb66d1f\gaborcsardi-notifier-d92b1b6/DESCRIPTION' (396ms)
# -  preparing 'notifier':
# v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
# -  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
# -  checking for empty or unneeded directories
# -  building 'notifier_1.0.0.tar.gz'
#    
# Installing package into 'C:/Users/r2/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWgKbkW/local_libpath_43ccbf98e2'
# (as 'lib' is unspecified)
# * installing *source* package 'notifier' ...
# ** R
# ** inst
# ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
# ** help
# *** installing help indices
#   converting help for package 'notifier'
#     finding HTML links ... done
#     notify                                  html  
# ** building package indices
# ** testing if installed package can be loaded
# *** arch - i386
# *** arch - x64
# * DONE (notifier)
# In R CMD INSTALL
# New packages found: 'notifier'
# Moving to: '\\myserver/r2evans/R/win.library/3.5'
# Cleaning up
```

Comment: @KyleDixon, I know a long time passed between when you asked and when I offered this answer, so you probably long-ago found some workaround for your issue. Would you consider posting your own workaround, and accept either yours or this answer?

Comment: I should have known ... even at the time I wrote this function (the first time ... this answer is not the first), there is [`withr::with_libpaths`](https://withr.r-lib.org/reference/with_libpaths.html) which does much of the same thing (though not the post-install copy).

Answer (score 4):

There is a standalone mode in `remotes`. This mode removes the dependency on `pkgbuild` that was the proximate cause of the error (the ultimate problem is much deeper in the call chain).

This is documented in the [`remotes` package readme](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes#standalone-mode).

You can force `remotes` to use the standalone mode with

```
Sys.setenv(R_REMOTES_STANDALONE="true")
```

This solution found thank to [gaborcsardi](https://github.com/r-lib/processx/issues/249#issuecomment-608452674)

Comment: I used this solution. I had to use the argument `build = F` and got a warning but it worked.