# R - Installation of shiny fails after upgrade to 4.0.2

Tags: r, shiny

I upgraded to R 4.0.2 today, and also updated my copy of RStudio. While I've been updating my packages I've found that shiny won't install. Whenever I try to install shiny I get the following message...

```
Error in as.list.environment(base::getNamespace("shiny"), all.names = TRUE) : 
  lazy-load database 'H:/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/shiny/R/shiny.rdb' is corrupt
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> as.list.environment
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Error in as.list.environment(base::getNamespace("shiny"), all.names = TRUE) : 
  lazy-load database 'H:/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/shiny/R/shiny.rdb' is corrupt
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> as.list.environment
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing 'H:/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/shiny'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
```

I get this error regardless of whether I just type "install.packages('shiny')" and peace out or if I download the tar.gz and try to install from a local directory. The same error happens when I specify to download an older version of shiny, so I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with the file I'm trying to install. Restarting RStudio does nothing, which is the only advice I could find online for shiny installation problems.

Has anyone else had any problems with installing shiny since upgrading to the newest version of R? Any workarounds?

Comment: Whenever I see `lazy-load ... is corrupt`, I typically restart R, move the affected package directories out of the way (often don't delete until I know that was the problem), and then reinstall the packages, and the problem usually goes away. When I say restart, I mean completely ... no `.Rdata` file or anything, as they can sometimes latch on to a package.

Comment: Just tried that. Same error was thrown.

Comment: Ahh, now I see it: installation of packages onto a network drive (with spaces, no less) has been (in the past) a source of errors. I don't know if it always causes errors, but there are enough issues with windows paths and network drives that an alternate solution is to install it elsewhere (and then optionally move it to this `H:/` path). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814948/3358272), I think it is worth trying as well.

Comment: Well hot damn, the method you used in the link worked. Thank you so much!