# Not able to use ggplot and gives an error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I installed ggplot2 with all the dependencies = TRUE

When I try to plot something, I get this error. Please help!
I tried uninstalling and installing R studio again but no success

```
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: AES, digest, digest2int, getVDigest, sha1, sha1_attr_digest, sha1_digest, hmac, makeRaw
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘print.AES’, ‘sha1.anova’, ‘sha1.array’, ‘sha1.call’, ‘sha1.character’, ‘sha1.complex’, ‘sha1.data.frame’, ‘sha1.Date’, ‘sha1.default’, ‘sha1.integer’, ‘sha1.factor’, ‘sha1.formula’, ‘sha1.function’, ‘sha1.logical’, ‘sha1.list’, ‘sha1.matrix’, ‘sha1.name’, ‘sha1.NULL’, ‘sha1.numeric’, ‘sha1.pairlist’, ‘sha1.POSIXct’, ‘sha1.POSIXlt’, ‘sha1.raw’, ‘sha1.(’, ‘makeRaw.default’, ‘makeRaw.digest’, ‘makeRaw.character’, ‘makeRaw.raw’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found 

[![Restart R and installed Digest : Following error occurs][1]][1]

 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARAwB.png
```

Comment: Try installing the `digest` package manually. (You might need to exit R and RStudio in order to do so, depending on where exactly the problem is coming from. Try first without restarting.)

Comment: What version of R are you running? When you get the error, what does `sessionInfo()` show (it should list all the versions of the packages currently loaded)

Comment: @r2evans How do i install digest? Can you please explain the process?

Comment: @MrFlick  Please check the attachment

Comment: Almost all packages are installed the same way. `install.packages("digest")`, maybe `install.packages("digest", dependencies = TRUE)` if it gives you trouble.

Comment: I get the same error when I load digest

Comment: @r2evans                                                                                                           Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘digest’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: AES, digest, digest2int, getVDigest, sha1, sha1_attr_digest, sha1_digest, hmac, makeRaw
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘print.AES’, ‘sha1.anova’, ‘sha1.array’, ‘sha1.call’, ‘sha1.character’, ‘sha1.complex’, ‘sha1.data.frame’, ‘sha1.Date’, ‘sha1.default’, ‘sha1.integer’, ‘sha1.factor’, ‘sha1.formula’, ‘sha1.function’, ‘sha1.logical’, ‘sha1.list’, ‘sha1.matrix, etc

Comment: Read my first comment again, and try *restarting R and RStudio* before trying to `install.packages("digest")`. Your `sessionInfo()` (which you should [edit] your question and insert into a code block *there*) suggests that you have not done this.

Comment: @r2evans I did what you explained. Please check the image attached to the question 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARAwB.png

Comment: You can't install packages directly onto OneDrive, for whatever reason Windows and R are broken in this regard. Close R. Close RStudio. Delete that directory. Start R. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814948/3358272, and use either `with_local_libpath` or `withr::with_libpaths` in a similar manner to install the package to *not onedrive* and then, if you must have it in onedrive (not sure why), then copy the completed-installation `digest` to your onedrive.

Comment: @r2evans Got it working. Deleted R and R studio. Created a new directory in R which is not on one drive. Changed the directory in R studio and installed it locally on the machine. While installing the libraries changed the directory to the local and everything is working now. Thanks so much for your help!