# Install R package without file append?

Tags: r, databricks, fuse

I'm looking for a way to install R packages on a file system that does not allow file appends (namely, the Databricks File System/DBFS, which is available via a FUSE mount).

It looks like `install.packages()` by default does some file-cleaning and file-appending to the stuff it downloads.

Does R offer a method to install packages without appending to files?

My experience so far looks like this:

```
foundpkgs: kernlab, /tmp/RtmprBtUFj/downloaded_packages/kernlab_0.9-29.tar.gz
files: /tmp/RtmprBtUFj/downloaded_packages/kernlab_0.9-29.tar.gz
* installing *source* package ‘kernlab’ ...
** package ‘kernlab’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-EkOYxp/r-base-4.0.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c brweight.cpp -o brweight.o
<...snip...>
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o kernlab.so brweight.o ctable.o cweight.o dbreakpt.o dcauchy.o dgpnrm.o dgpstep.o dprecond.o dprsrch.o dspcg.o dtron.o dtrpcg.o dtrqsol.o esa.o expdecayweight.o inductionsort.o init.o kspectrumweight.o lcp.o misc.o msufsort.o solvebqp.o stringk.o stringkernel.o svm.o wkasailcp.o wmsufsort.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /dbfs/<...snip...>/00LOCK-kernlab/00new/kernlab/libs
** R
Warning in .file_append_ensuring_LFs(outFile, codeFiles) :
  write error during file append
<...snip...>
Warning in .file_append_ensuring_LFs(outFile, codeFiles) :
  write error during file append
Error in .install_package_code_files(".", instdir) : 
  unable to write code files
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package ‘kernlab’
* removing ‘/dbfs/<...snip...>/kernlab’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmprBtUFj/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: DBFS is commonly used to store the data objects, not your executables. Why are  you trying to store your R packages there?

Comment: I agree that installing on there might not be best, but ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814948/3358272 is an answer that does the compiling/installation on a different filesystem and then copy it onto this DBFS mount.

Comment: @crestor Because otherwise the R environment, including user-installed packages, gets wiped out by Databricks on cluster restart. It's hard to sell our internal data science users on that kind of DevEx.

Comment: Same response to @r2evans: I am happy with the DevEx, but my data scientist users wouldn't be.

Comment: So you're telling me that there is no other filesystem available to R on this system? How about `tmpfs`? I suspect that your data scientist users will be less pleased with not being able to install certain packages *at all*. If you can use `/tmp/` or similar, then you're good to go, otherwise I think this DBFS solution is either ephemeral or a show-stopper.

Comment: Yes, @r2evans, these are shared machines. Databricks creates a temporary user for the duration of the R session, then wipes the user's home directory on cluster restart. I could dump every user's installed packages into a filesystem location that all users share on this shared cluster, but that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Have you ever done CI testing of R packages (or any language that requires dependent modules/packages)? Usually there is a "cache" of these dependent modules. If the cache exists and all modules' installation files are found within it, then the modules are installed from that cache directory; if not, then they must be downloaded ... and then they are stored in the cache. There's nothing in what you've told me so far that **mandates** that a package must be installed on a DBFS, just that you want to use it as a cache for packages. So ... store the `.tar.gz` files there.

Comment: Or ... do as I suggested before, and use the users' home directories (not DBFS) to first compile and install the packages, and *then* move/copy the post-install package directories onto your DBFS. Why won't that work?

Comment: Following your first suggestion, @r2evans, how would I configure R to cache tarballs in DBFS when a user invokes `install.packages()` to install an arbitrary package?

Comment: I'm obviously not familiar with how databricks sets up filesystems or handles non-temp storing or caching, nor with your role in this. If you cannot have users change their `repos` option; cannot ask them to use an ancillary function that does the compilation in a temporary non-DBFS location and installation into the DBFS location; and cannot ask them to use a cache of sorts, then ... I think you're out of options.

Comment: Please stand by the suggestions you make. Your second suggestion, with few changes, would work. I could make one folder on a local filesystem and another in DBFS, configure R to install packages into the local one and fall back to the other one when the local disk gets wiped, and then have a cron job to rsync the two. Your first suggestion is that I could configure R to avoid this extra complexity. What did you have in mind? If you're curious about my role, it's to make our users unaware of this setup, so they can go on invoking `install.packages()` just as they did when running R locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to allow the users to use `install.packages`, then my first suggestion is not an option, since it requires the use of an ancillary function. I think your comment walk-through makes the most sense if you can do it:

1. Prepend two directories to the lib-path, in order:

   ```r
   .libPaths(c("/localfs/", "/dbfs/", .libPaths())
   ```

   By prepending it to the existing `.libPaths()`, we are preserving what is available in the system library path. By putting `/localfs/` *first*, it is now the default location where any packages will be installed.
2. Either via some cron job or perhaps as a close-out function, make sure the two paths are in-sync:

   ```sh
   rsync -pr /localfs/* /dbfs/
   ```

   If you have some form of pre-exit script capability in the system, then this should only need to be done once; if you cannot trust it (perhaps the systems shut down immediately and/or have a timeout), then a cron job would suffice, if imperfectly.

   This means that it is likely that a package will be available in *both*, but R is fine with that.

   The one problem with this is if a newer installation does not have all of the same files as a previous install of it; think of a package that actually *reduces* its footprint for some reason (rare, perhaps, but possible). For this, you would need to use `rsync --delete ...`. However, while this makes sense, I have not tested it, so I strongly urge that you test this before trusting it unsupervised in production. (I mean, what could *possibly* go wrong with an arbitrary shell-script deleting files recursively ...)

Comment: I hope I sufficiently detailed the points in our discussion in the question comments.