# Issues Installing ggpubr; R Studio Version 4.1.3

Tags: r, ggpubr

I am rather new to r, and I am struggling with pulling up ggpubr into the library.

My code starts like this. I already have 'tidyverse' successfully installed:

```r
install.packages('ggpubr', lib = 'C:/CustomR')
```

This returns:

```r
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
also installing the dependencies ‘pkgload’, ‘praise’, ‘waldo’, ‘testthat’, ‘numDeriv’, ‘SparseM’, ‘MatrixModels’, ‘sp’, ‘minqa’, ‘nloptr’, ‘RcppEigen’, ‘carData’, ‘abind’, ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’, ‘maptools’, ‘lme4’, ‘corrplot’, ‘car’, ‘ggrepel’, ‘ggsci’, ‘cowplot’, ‘ggsignif’, ‘gridExtra’, ‘polynom’, ‘rstatix’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/pkgload_1.2.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 155868 bytes (152 KB)
downloaded 152 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/praise_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 19837 bytes (19 KB)
downloaded 19 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/waldo_0.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 102183 bytes (99 KB)
downloaded 99 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/testthat_3.1.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2558147 bytes (2.4 MB)
downloaded 2.4 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/numDeriv_2016.8-1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 116205 bytes (113 KB)
downloaded 113 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/SparseM_1.81.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1066525 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/MatrixModels_0.5-0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 429091 bytes (419 KB)
downloaded 419 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/sp_1.4-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2200540 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/minqa_1.2.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 855878 bytes (835 KB)
downloaded 835 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/nloptr_2.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1749120 bytes (1.7 MB)
downloaded 1.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/RcppEigen_0.3.3.9.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2870044 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/carData_3.0-5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1820557 bytes (1.7 MB)
downloaded 1.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/abind_1.4-5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 63748 bytes (62 KB)
downloaded 62 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/pbkrtest_0.5.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 356907 bytes (348 KB)
downloaded 348 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/quantreg_5.88.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1943351 bytes (1.9 MB)
downloaded 1.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/maptools_1.1-3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2220324 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/lme4_1.1-28.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 5349300 bytes (5.1 MB)
downloaded 5.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/corrplot_0.92.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3844791 bytes (3.7 MB)
downloaded 3.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/car_3.0-12.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1413444 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/ggrepel_0.9.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1119220 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/ggsci_2.9.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2978469 bytes (2.8 MB)
downloaded 2.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/cowplot_1.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1375525 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/ggsignif_0.6.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 600832 bytes (586 KB)
downloaded 586 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/gridExtra_2.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1109446 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/polynom_1.4-0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 312672 bytes (305 KB)
downloaded 305 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/rstatix_0.7.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 606899 bytes (592 KB)
downloaded 592 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/ggpubr_0.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1906849 bytes (1.8 MB)
downloaded 1.8 MB

package ‘pkgload’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘praise’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘waldo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘testthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘numDeriv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘SparseM’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘MatrixModels’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘sp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘minqa’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘nloptr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘RcppEigen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘carData’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘abind’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘pbkrtest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘quantreg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘maptools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘lme4’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘corrplot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘car’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘ggrepel’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘ggsci’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘cowplot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘ggsignif’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘gridExtra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘polynom’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘rstatix’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘ggpubr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\alitt\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWGGjmm\downloaded_packages
```

---

It appears to me that based upon one of the last lines that package 'ggpubr' successfully unpacked.

So, I ran this:

```r
library(ggpubr)
```

And this error message returned:

```
Error in library(ggpubr) : there is no package called ‘ggpubr’
```

---

I'm at a loss, and I appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Did you install ``Rtools`` like it says?

Comment: @user438383 I was thinking the same thing, but because it downloaded the `.zip` (binary) package and later said `package ‘ggpubr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`, I'm inclined to believe that that warning may not be the culprit. Anna, can you look in each of the directories listed in `.libPaths()` and see if you can find the `ggpubr` subdirectory? If so, I suggest you restart R (though I don't know why that is necessary here). If not, well, something else is happening, and I'm with you ... at a loss.

Comment: @r2evans This helps. I discovered that the library path is pointing to my OneDrive. Since that is not writable for RStudio, I added the custom path in the original install.packages() code.  I went to my custom folder, copied all of the subdirectories and pasted them into the OneDrive folder. A little backwards, but it works, and I can move forward.  Many thanks!

Comment: FYI, there are so many problems with building/installing R packages into an R-library on a onedrive; while I cannot explain all of them well (nor in this constrained space), it suggests that installing them locally (not onedrive) *first*, and then if you really want them in the onedrive, move the installed package directory later. Since you don't have write access, perhaps you don't even need it in your `.libPaths()`?

Comment: If you resolved your own problem, then post your solution below as an answer to help others. Please do not edit your original question just to say "resolved". By posting an answer below you allow other members of the community to upvote that answer or supply alternative answers.

Comment: If `.libPaths()` is not pointing to the directoy where your packages  are installed, or where you want them to be installed, edit your `etc/Rprofile.site` file with `.Library.site <- "full/path/to/library/dir"`. You can have more than one, R will look them up in the order they are in this variable.

Comment: @r2evans Agreed, finding this out the hard way. Will edit .libPaths() for the long-term. Thanks!

Comment: @RuiBarradas This is very helpful for the long-term. Thanks!

Comment: Anna, perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814948/3358272 will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that the library path is pointing to my OneDrive. Since that is not writable for RStudio, I added the custom path in the original install.packages() code. I went to my custom folder, copied all of the subdirectories and pasted them into the OneDrive folder. A little backwards, but it works, and I can move forward. Many thanks!