# Failing to start RStudio after reinstalling everything

Tags: r, rstudio

I am a novice to using R and trying to access RStudio on a network drive and I reinstalled both R and RStudio but unable to open the RStudio. I can open R and have tried the following code:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "\\\\wechu/dfsroots/UserData/kbanipal/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.3/library"
```

Below is a copy of the error report that I get:

````
## R Session Startup Failure Report

### RStudio Version

RStudio 2022.02.1+461, "Prairie Trillium" (8aaa5d47, 2022-03-17) for Windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

### Error message

The R session had a fatal error.

Unexpected exception: rstudio_boost::filesystem::status: The network name cannot be found: "//wechu"

### Process Output

The R session exited with code 2. 

Error output:

```
[No errors emitted]
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

### Logs

*C:/Users/kbanipal/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-kbanipal.log*

```
2022-04-20T16:50:58.775690Z [rsession-kbanipal] ERROR system error 67 (The network name cannot be found) [path: //wechu/]; OCCURRED AT bool __cdecl rstudio::core::FilePath::exists(void) const src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:885; LOGGED FROM: bool __cdecl rstudio::core::FilePath::exists(void) const src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:885
2022-04-20T16:50:58.925914Z [rsession-kbanipal] ERROR Unexpected exception: rstudio_boost::filesystem::status: The network name cannot be found: "//wechu"; LOGGED FROM: int __cdecl rstudio::r::session::RReadConsole(const char *,char *,int,int) src/cpp/r/session/RStdCallbacks.cpp:416
2022-04-20T16:50:58.925914Z [rsession-kbanipal] ERROR Unexpected exception: rstudio_boost::filesystem::status: The network name cannot be found: "//wechu"; LOGGED FROM: int __cdecl rstudio::r::session::RReadConsole(const char *,char *,int,int) src/cpp/r/session/RStdCallbacks.cpp:416

```
````

Anyone has any idea on what I can do? Thank you!

Comment: `The network name cannot be found) [path: //wechu/` seems fairly direct. Try removing that from your `.libPaths()` (perhaps in your `~/.Rprofile`) and restarting. FYI, the use of network drives for package-installation can be problematic in many ways, though mostly during compiling/installation of new packages, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57777382/3358272.