# Install package through batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, r-package, installation-package

I am trying to share some R code with a few colleagues that are not familiar with R at all. To avoid them trying to understand R and running a script I created a batch file to just run the file without them doing anything, just double-clicking on the ".bat" file.

I've tried it and it works perfectly fine. But then I added a few lines in my Rscript to make sure the needed libraries were installed and, if not, to install them. That is when my batch file stopped working.

I've checked with another R script that just does `install.packages(package_name)` and the result I got is: the batch file does nothing.

So how can I run a R script that does install libraries through a batch file??

---

My atempt:

My extremely simple batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\SomeFolder\test.R"
EXIT
```

And my "test.R" script:

```
list.of.packages <- c("lubridate","tidyverse","Z10")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
```

I also tried `install.packages(new.packages,repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")` but it doesn't work either.

Note: I know my code works because if I run it inside R it does the job.

Comment: Some thoughts: (1) make sure your `.libPaths()` is correctly set in the script, and the directory exists, noting that `HOME` on windows is not always what users expect. And (2) installing packages interactively on a OneDrive or similar network-folder-thingy is often problematic, resulting in odd failures that go away when it is installed _outside_ of the OneDrive dir structure and moved into place. While it sounds odd, it is unfortunately not uncommon. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814948/3358272.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick answer! I am actually new to this whole batch file thing, lots of googling around led me to that. I'm not really sure I understand the `.libPaths()` thing, if you could somehow walk me through it I would really appreciate it.

Comment: When I open my "test.R" file (located on a OneDrive  path) in R and run it it does work, so I'm not sure where things have started to go sideways...

Comment: Does the output from `.libPaths()` in the script look like it does when run in an interactive R session? If there is a difference, then it might be that packages are not (or can not be) installed to the expected location.

Comment: When I run the script through the batch file I don't see anything, but it is supposed to work like that. I'm not sure how to get the `.libPaths()` output when running the batch file though.

Comment: it is likely putting its output *somewhere*, check for `*.Rout` files

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that. Thank you so much, I'm such a newbie here and thank you for your patience! This is the message within the `.Rout`  file: `Installing package into 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> contrib.url
Aborted execution` (not sure about the exact wording of the last line, I'm translating)

Comment: You need to set `options(repos=...)` in your script, perhaps `options(repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")` or whichever mirror you prefer.

Comment: Oh my god you just saved me! Thank you so much! If you want to, write your comment as an answer and I'll sure upvote it and accept it :)

Comment: One more question, though. What is the difference between setting `options(repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")` at the begining of my script and doing `install.packages(new.packages,repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")`? Just curious because this is my first attempt at this and I would like to know why one works and the other doesn't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this doesn't work,

```r
install.packages(new.packages,repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

but your error message (in the comments) of

```r
Installing package into 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2' (as 'lib' is unspecified)
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") :
    trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror Calls: install.packages -> contrib.url 
Aborted execution
```

indicates that it isn't seeing `repos`. (I *suspect* that you had another error when you had `install.packages(..., repos=)` and, because you were not looking at the `.Rout` file you didn't see *that* error. But I don't know for sure.)

If the `install.packages(..., repos=)` isn't working, you can always set it using

```r
options(repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

earlier in your batch file, and it should work.