# Can't install packages in R

Tags: r, installation, package, stringr

[Asking for a colleague because his post is considered as a spam by the website bot.]

I am trying to install the package `stringr` on R.

I ran `install.packages("stringr")` in RStudio and it raised an error. Then, I try installing it from the terminal and it raised a similar error, see below. Any package I try to install raises the same issue.

I have Windows 10 but I do not have admin rights. I have R version 4.0.5. I installed R and RStudio via Anaconda. By the way, it seems that there is an issue with Rtools. The content of .Renviron is `PATH="${RTOOLS42_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"` (as it should be I guess) but `Sys.which("make")` returns `""` in Rstudio. One last thing, my R home environment is on my OneDrive folder, maybe this causes the issue?

Any idea?

```
C:\Users\TDOUENN>Rscript -e "install.packages('stringr', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"                            
Installing package into 'C:/Users/TDOUENN/OneDrive - UvA/Documents/My_RLibs'                                            
(as 'lib' is unspecified)                                                                                               
also installing the dependencies 'cli', 'rlang', 'lifecycle'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:                                                          

binary source needs_compilation                                                                               

cli        3.2.0  3.6.0              TRUE                                                                               
rlang      1.0.2  1.0.6              TRUE                                                                              
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE                                                                              
stringr    1.4.0  1.5.0             FALSE        

Binaries will be installed                                                                                            

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.zip'                                             
Content type 'application/zip' length 1255499 bytes (1.2 MB)                                                            
==================================================                                                                      
downloaded 1.2 MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_1.0.2.zip'                                           
Content type 'application/zip' length 1718546 bytes (1.6 MB)                                                            
==================================================                                                                      
downloaded 1.6 MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
package 'cli' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked                                                                
package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked                                                                                                                                                                                      
The downloaded binary packages are in                                                                                           
C:\Users\TDOUENN\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkPFcWJ\downloaded_packages                                              
installing the source packages 'lifecycle', 'stringr'                                                                                                                                                                                           
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz'                                                
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB)                                                          
==================================================                                                                      
downloaded 104 KB                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stringr_1.5.0.tar.gz'                                                  
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 175699 bytes (171 KB)                                                          
==================================================                                                                      
downloaded 171 KB                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...                                                                           
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked                                                       
** using staged installation                                                                                            
** R                                                                                                                    
** inst                                                                                                                 
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading                                                                    
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :                                              
namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required                                                     
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace                         
Execution halted                                                                                                        
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'                                                                      
* removing 'C:/Users/TDOUENN/OneDrive - UvA/Documents/My_RLibs/lifecycle'                                               
* installing *source* package 'stringr' ...                                                                             
** package 'stringr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked                                                         
** using staged installation                                                                                            
** R                                                                                                                    
** data                                                                                                                 
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB                                                                                      
** inst                                                                                                                 
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading                                                                    
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :                                   
namespace 'lifecycle' 1.0.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.3 is required                                                 
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace                                              
Execution halted                                                                                                        
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'stringr'                                                                        
* removing 'C:/Users/TDOUENN/OneDrive - UvA/Documents/My_RLibs/stringr'                                                                                                                                                                         
The downloaded source packages are in                                                                                           
'C:\Users\TDOUENN\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkPFcWJ\downloaded_packages'                                            
Warning messages:                                                                                                       
1: In install.packages("stringr", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :                                                  
installation of package 'lifecycle' had non-zero exit status                                                          
2: In install.packages("stringr", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :                                                  
installation of package 'stringr' had non-zero exit status                                                                                                                                                                                    
C:\Users\TDOUENN>Rscript -e "install.packages('stringr', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

Comment: (1) `Sys.which("make")` returning `""` is problematic, confirm that `file.exists("c:/rtools42/usr/bin/make.exe")` is true? (2) As an alternative to Rtools42 not being found, you can use Posit's many-binary-packages available via its repo, see https://packagemanager.rstudio.com. (3) For `namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required`, completely close and restart R and RStudio, making sure to start in a clean session (i.e., no `.Rdata`/`.Rprofile` influence) and then `install.packages("rlang")` to update it, then try the rest again.

Comment: On Windows binary packages are used by default. Use `type = "source"`, e.g. `install.packages('stringr', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/', type = 'source')`. Make sure you're able to compile from source. For more info read `?install.packages`

Comment: [Responding for my colleague as he hasn't enough reputation to comment.] 
@r2evans the file exists, so I guess there is no need to test your solution (2)? Also, I don't really understand what I am supposed to do with Posit.

`install.packages("rlang")` doesn't work because of lack of admin rights: 
```Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying ...\OneDrive - UvA\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to ...\OneDrive - UvA\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied```

@AndreWildberg same problem if we install from source.

Comment: The fact that `file.exists(.)` is true suggests several problems, but I fear at this point they are moot. As for admin rights, two things: (1) never never never use OneDrive as a place to compile/install packages; it can be used once already compiled and ready, but it fails heavily for the act of compiling/installing, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814948/3358272 for discussion; and (2) if you cannot somehow get a new directory and upgrade `rlang` (it's possible to have different versions installed in diff libpaths), you cannot install the current versions of packages you want.

Comment: The "Permission denied" problem could be because you have two copies of R running at the same time. Are you sure all other R and RStudio sessions are closed? You cannot update a DLL while it's in use. Maybe restart the computer first just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

Based on these lines from the error message:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :                                              
namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
```

And this error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :                                   
namespace 'lifecycle' 1.0.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.3 is required                                                 
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace                                              
Execution halted
```

It looks like your colleague needs to update their lifecycle and rlang packages in order to install stringr.

Comment: Sure but R should handle that itself. It would be quite cumbersome if R doesn't manage the dependencies automatically when installing a package.