# Installed Rtools, R says it is not installed

Tags: r, rtools

I've followed the instructions here to a T

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

When I run the test on the jsonlite package I still get

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
```

and then

```
Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory 'C:/Users/fl014036/Documents/R/R-3.6.2/library'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jsonlite’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/47539125/5784831?

Comment: @Christoph possibly....I saw some lines in there that seemed to help. The 2 Sys.setenv ones. It has eliminated my warning that rtools is not installed but I still have the permission error. That sounds like I need to run as admin. Will test that out.

Comment: What R version are you running (seems like 3.6.2)? What version of RTools did you install?