# sourcing Rcpp locally works, but doesn't in parallelization

Tags: r, rcpp, parallel.foreach

Hi I used to use Rcpp code and parallelize it to several cores, but after changing my desktop it does not work anymore.

For example, I'm trying to run the following code,

```
rm(list = ls())
options(repos = c(CRAN = "http://cran.rstudio.com"))

n_cluster <- 2


## library ----------------------------------------------------------
name_pkg <- c(
  # Parallelization
  "foreach",
  "doParallel",
  
  # Rcpp
  "Rcpp"
)
name_pkg <- unique(name_pkg)
invisible(lapply(name_pkg, library, character.only = T)) # load multiple packages


## Assign clusters for parallel computing ----------------------------------------------------------
cl <- makeCluster(n_cluster, outfile = "/Users/Sungshin/Desktop/Result_verbose.txt")
registerDoParallel(cl)


## start -------------------------------------------------------------------
res_fit <- foreach(i = 1:4, .packages = name_pkg) %dopar% {
  evalCpp("1+1")
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

but it returns

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "Error 1 occurred building shared library."
```

- **However**, I can run `evalCpp("1+1")` on the local Rstudio (when not parallelized). Therefore, I think I have all prepared (locally) to run Rcpp code, but the error persists when combined with parallel computing.
- I checked the outfile("/Users/Sungshin/Desktop/Result_verbose.txt"), but nothing was reported.
- `writeLines(strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";")[[1L]])` gives me this:

```
\usr\bin
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
C:\Users\Sungshin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\
C:\Users\Sungshin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\
C:\Users\Sungshin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64
C:\rtools40\mingw64\bin
```

Could anyone help me with this? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Likely duplicate; easiest way to get code onto worker nodes in a cluster in to organize the code _in a package that you load on each node_.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks, but I think there must be a situation where we don't want to build a package if the codes are not tested well enough and thus will be changed continuousely.

Comment: Sure. But then you need to rebuild the compiled function on each node.  Because just wishing for it doesn't move it there, portably.  As I said, it's all been discussed before.

Comment: The `rcpp` tag is currently at 2586 question. I know each and every one of us is truly special, but with 2500 question some have in fact been asked before.  The search function here may be the very best friend you did not know you had...

Comment: Doesn't sourcing Rcpp code inside of `foreach` compile it on each node? Of course, I will also look at `rcpp` tagged postings more.

Comment: "if the codes are not tested well enough and thus will be changed continuousely[sic]" is not a reason for not building a package. Building a package is easy. It doesn't require code to be tested well and allows developing code.

Comment: I don't think so, @Roland. Every time you change your code, it would be bothersome to build a new package no matter how easy it is.

Comment: Try devtools then.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Roland, but what do you mean by that? Does devtools lessen the burden of building R package dramatically? Would you be able to share your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me, but I found out what was missing.

I added this `C:/rtools40/usr/bin` to the system path (by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47557831/4008219)).

I thought one of the added, `C:\rtools40\mingw64\bin`, is the right one, but turns out not. Hope no one is confused with what I just learned in future.