# Can't install 'glmnet' in R

Tags: r, glmnet

I put in this code:

```
install.packages("glmnet")
```

And it delivers this error message:

```
* installing *source* package 'glmnet' ...
** package 'glmnet' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
"c:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"g++  -std=gnu++14 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.4/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Users/zac.t8/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppEigen/include' -I'C:/Users/zac.t8/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'     -Iglmnetpp/include -Iglmnetpp/src -Iglmnetpp/test    -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
sh: c:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.4/etc/i386/Makeconf:229: RcppExports.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'glmnet'
* removing 'C:/Users/zac.t8/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/glmnet'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glmnet’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can someone point out what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You need to have RTools installed (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html), and in your `PATH`.

Comment: Thank you. How do I put RTools into my PATH?

Comment: Have you checked out this question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47557831/3212698

Comment: @mhovd ; R is still at R-4.1.3 so https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html is probably a better fit. zact8; see this link on how to set the paths. But as you are on Windows, why not just install the glmnet binary?